# Filepond - Not supported image types

Tags: filepond

When trying to upload .arw and .ct2 files, I am getting the 'Image type not supported' error message in the file status area. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUHhS.png)

So here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to add support for .arw and .ct2 file types?
2. Is it possible to know what other file types are not currently supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This particular error message was generated by FilePondPluginImageValidateSize, as it obviously does not support these file types.
Setting allowImageValidateSize to 'false' solved this for me.

Still would be nice to know exactly what image types are not supported by this plugin, if possible :) Haven't found this info in the docs.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, As FilePond is based on browser tech it supports what the browser supports, you can find an overview here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rik. Both for your answer and for the great library